# Does enumerateObjectsUsingBlock always always iterates sequentially?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, fast-enumeration

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *tool, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog("Idx :: %d",idx);  
}];
```

Will the log print indexes sequentially starting from 0 ... till end?
If YES, How is it faster than fast enumeration of kind for (obj in array)?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? It says it "starts with the first object and continues through to the last object". It's most likely just as fast as fast enumeration.

Comment: Fast enumeration puts elements of collection into on-stack C-array, thus removing the need to call anything to get next element on each iteration. Actual difference may be unnoticeable. Read more on "fast enumeration" in Xcode docs.